# Alexa Skill works locally but not when testing in the skill developer portal

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am running an Node.js mqtt subscriber server on my raspberry pi that listens for published events by my lambda aws code.The publish event is triggered via an Alexa Skill event.

Example;

"Alexa, tell TV to change to channel 10" - This intent is then recognised by my Lambda code as a ChannelNumberIntent intent which then publishes the correct message with the channel number to my mqtt server on my Raspi. Raspi then does the changing channel logic.

I've run this all locally using the alexa-app-server and it works completely fine. Response from Alexa works and mqtt server receives the correct digits/message packet.

The problem arises when I test using the Alexa skill in the developer skill portal on the test tab. It runs fine, returns a response from the lambda saying message received but the mqtt subscriber never receives the channel digits/message packet? I believe somewhere after hours of puzzling my lambda code is messed up. Here is my code;

**LAMBDA AWS CODE**

```
    'use strict';
module.change_code = 1;
var Alexa = require('alexa-app');
var skill = new Alexa.app('tvRemote');
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var deviceName = "tvRemote";
var _ = require('lodash');
var path = require('path');

var host = "randomletters.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";

//App id is the skill being used.
var app_id = "amzn1.ask.skill.more random letters";

var thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({

    keyPath: path.join(__dirname, '/Raspi.private.key'),
    certPath: path.join(__dirname, '/Raspi.cert.pem'),
    caPath: path.join(__dirname, '/root-CA.crt'),
    clientId: deviceName,
    region: "us-east-1",
});

var reprompt = 'I didn\'t hear a channel, tell me a channel number or name to change to that channel';

skill.launch(function (request, response) {
    var prompt = 'To change channel, tell me a channel number.';
    response.say(prompt).reprompt(reprompt).shouldEndSession(true);
});

skill.intent('ChannelNumberIntent', {
        'slots': {
            'CHANNELNUMBER': 'CHANNELID'
        },
        'utterances': ['{|Change|put} {|the|on} {|channel} {|to} {-|CHANNELNUMBER}']
    },
    function (request, response) {
        var channelNumber = request.slot('CHANNELNUMBER');

        if (_.isEmpty(channelNumber)) {
            var prompt = 'I didn\'t hear a channel code. Tell me a channel code.';
            response.say(prompt).shouldEndSession(true);
            return true;
        } else {

            thingShadows.publish('lambda/channelNumber', channelNumber, function () {
                var prompt1 = 'Okay.';
                response.say(prompt1).shouldEndSession(false);
                return true;
            });


            return true;

        }


    }
);

module.exports = skill;
```

**MQTT SERVER**

```
   'use strict'

var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/Raspi.private.key'))
var CERT = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/Raspi.cert.pem'))
var TRUSTED_CA_LIST = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/root-CA.crt'))

var PORT = Corretportnumber
var HOST = 'RASPIHOSTWORDSASDFSDF.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

var options = {
    port: PORT,
    host: HOST,
    key: KEY,
    cert: CERT,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    // The CA list will be used to determine if server is authorized
    ca: TRUSTED_CA_LIST
}

var client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://' + HOST, options)

client.subscribe('lambda/channelNumber')

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    if (topic === 'lambda/channelNumber') {

      //  logic.changeChannelCode(message);

        console.log(message.toString());


    }
})
```

Obviously hid host and port numbers for reasons

Comment: Are you supplying any skill-specific data to the server, like `userId`, or `user`, for example? If so, this data is only available when triggering your skill locally, and not from the developer portal.

Comment: @MikiP Hi, i'm not sure what you mean, I send some JSON to the Lambda - with session id and user id etc. This is then picked up by the Lambda and runs correctly apart from; 

`thingShadows.publish('lambda/channelNumber', channelNumber, function () { var prompt1 = 'Okay.'; response.say(prompt1).shouldEndSession(false); return true; });`

 Which doesn't seem to run the publish but does run the response any ideas?Althought the response is inside the publish function? (seems that way in my eyes, i'm new to node.js and javascript though)

Comment: Have you tried testing via the lambda console?